# How to Consolidate Data on a Log Using FILTER() Which Causes #REF Errors?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on an expiration log for consumer goods and need to consolidate expiration dates from three separate logs. Each date has multiple products, so I opted to use the FILTER() function where FILTER(product column, date column=A1) where column A in this "master" log represents dates.

For context, there are 2000+ rows and this function is giving me the #REF! error because of out-of-bounds output arrays. Is there a faster way of consolidating this data without having to parse through every date for thousands of rows?

I've tried to FILTER() by each date, but this has taken hours and I have two other logs to consolidate into this master copy.

This is a sample inventory watch for Location 1. Notice there are several items on some dates.

[image]

This is a sample inventory watch for Location 2. The dates are all supposed to vary.

[image]

I cannot drag down the formula for each date for its X amount of items without receiving the #REF! error because of spillover.

[image]

This is my desired result, "master log", without having to manual measure out the amount of items per date & continually pasting the formula at the start of each date to avoid the error. #NAs are negligible.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `each date`? Post few sample data then show your desired output. Additionally you can share a link of your dummy sheet.

Comment: I added images.

Comment: `I added images.` "Please **DO NOT** post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question." [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). IMHO, your image of the #REF! error is OK _except_ that there is no context of row/column numbers for cell B4. Ditto the "master log" except that you haven't explained the formula that you used to populate Columns B & C.

Comment: I see. The formula goes as follows: =FILTER(product column by location, date column by location=date listed on master log)

Comment: You might find that using ‘if error’ or ‘if a’ might work with your formula to avoid the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to combine your data from several sheets, identify it by location, and sort it by date.

This answer uses `QUERY` to provide two options:

**Option#1** - duplicate dates for all locations

`=query({{"Date","Location 1","Location 2"};query({Sheet1!A2:C8},"select Col2, Col3,' ' where Col2 is not null label ' ' ''");query({Sheet2!A2:C8},"select Col2,' ', Col3 where Col2 is not null label ' ' ''")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 order by Col1")`

**RESULTS**

[image: option1]

- `QUERY` is used to stack the data from each of the sheets (just 2xsheets in this case - "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".
- `{"Date","Location 1","Location 2"}` - The header - 3 x columns
- `;` - the array divider. This means that the data will be "stacked" one on  top of the other
- `query({Sheet1!A2:C8},"select Col2, Col3,' ' where Col2 is not null label ' ' ''")`

  - Note the source starts at row#2; ignoring the header
  - Sheet1: `"select Col2, Col3,' '`  - a blank column is added in Column 3.

    - This allows Col3 to be placed in the "Location 1" column and the blank value will be in the "Location 2" column
  - Sheet2: `"select Col2,' ', Col3` - a blank column is added between Col2 and Col3

    - This allows Col3 to be placed in the "Location 2" column and the blank value will be in the "Location 1" column
- `order by Col1` - results are sorted by Date

---

**Option#2** - remove duplicate dates per location; comma separated values per location

`=query({{"Date","Location 1", "Location 2"};query({ARRAYFORMULA(query(value({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:B&"×", Sheet1!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))}),"select Col1")),ARRAYFORMULA(query({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:B&"×", Sheet1!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))},"select Col2"))},"select Col1, Col2, ' ' label ' ' ''");query({ARRAYFORMULA(query(value({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet2!B2:B&"×", Sheet2!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet2!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))}),"select Col1")),ARRAYFORMULA(query({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet2!B2:B&"×", Sheet2!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet2!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))},"select Col2"))},"select Col1, ' ', Col2 label ' ' ''")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 order by Col1")`

**RESULTS**

[image: option2]

h/t: @player0 [How to create a comma separate aggregate in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323648/1330560)

---

Option#1 - 3 locations

`=query({ {"Date","Location 1","Location 2","Location 3"}; query({Sheet1!A2:C8},"select Col2, Col3,' ','  ' where Col2 is not null label ' ' '','  ' ''"); query({Sheet2!A2:C8},"select Col2,' ', Col3,'  ' where Col2 is not null label ' ' '','  ' ''"); query({Sheet3!A2:C8},"select Col2,' ','  ', Col3 where Col2 is not null label ' ' '','  ' ''")}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 order by Col1")`

Option#2 - 3 Locations

`=query({ {"Date","Location 1", "Location 2","Location 3"}; query({ ARRAYFORMULA(query(value({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:B&"×", Sheet1!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)}, "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))}),"select Col1")), ARRAYFORMULA(query({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:B&"×", Sheet1!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))},"select Col2"))},"select Col1, Col2, ' ', '  ' label ' ' '','  ' ''"); query({ ARRAYFORMULA(query(value({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet2!B2:B&"×", Sheet2!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet2!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))}),"select Col1")),ARRAYFORMULA(query({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet2!B2:B&"×", Sheet2!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet2!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))},"select Col2"))},"select Col1, ' ', Col2,'  ' label ' ' '','  ' ''"); query({ ARRAYFORMULA(query(value({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet3!B2:B&"×", Sheet3!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet3!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))}),"select Col1")),ARRAYFORMULA(query({trim(split(flatten(query(QUERY({Sheet3!B2:B&"×", Sheet3!C2:C&",", ROW(Sheet3!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))},"select Col2"))},"select Col1, ' ', '  ',Col2 label ' ' '','  ' ''")}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3,Col4 order by Col1")`

Comment: How would the formula look with 3 locations?

Comment: Refer update of answer